# linear regression with two categorial independent variables and a continuous dependent variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, continuous-data, linear

I measured the amount of inflammation among patients as a categorical variable (mild/moderate/strong), I also measured the amount of disability of the patients using a questionnaire (score 0-23) 8 times in total over the course of a year. 
I want to know if patients in different groups of inflammation differ in disability score over the course of a year. What test should I use for this in spss?

Comment: Could you please provide details of your analysis? Variable of interest, dependent variable and estimation technique used.

Comment: The dependent variable of interest is the RDQ score (ordinal)
The two independent variables of interest are inflammation (categorial/ordinal) and time (ordinal/catagorial). I tried the binary log regression test in spss but since my dependent variable was not binary it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand well you want to answer the following research question: What is the effect of inflammation on disability?

The binary logistic regression requires the DV to be dicotomous, in your case the DV can take 24 different values (0-23).
The models that are used in the case of categorical DV are multinomial/ordered logits/probits. However, I would not treat the DV, RDQ index, as a categorical variable.

In your case you would end up with 24-1 coefficients values for each explanatory variable.

If OLS assumptions for your case hold, I suggest to try a linear model. The OLS output will provide the effect of moderate and strong inflammation on RDQ index (compared to the mild level of inflammation). No need to run any test. Most statistical softwares treat automatically categorical variables as a set of dummies. The interpretaion is straight forward.  However, machines are stupid, so you must tell them that the variable is a factor!

Rememeber that the OLS normality assumption must hold for the errors, and not for the DV. However, check the distribution of your DV, a simple frequency plot may give a general idea of what you are dealing with.

After estimation of the OLS, check the distribution of the errors (normal qq-plot), plus other post estimation diagnostics in order to understand if you are using the correct functional form.

EDIT:
(This is too long for a comment so I post it here)

Of course you can try with semi-parametric and parametric models. Actually they are not variant of OLS, for obvious reasons. 
However, their application requires a bit of experience. I suggest to try to fit the model carefully having in mind all possible source of bias that can arise. 
Namely, are you omitting variables correlated with inflammation? Is there a reverse causality among disability and iflammation? That is, does inflammation casuse greater disability, and disability greater inflammation? Is you sample random? If just one of the above hold, you may want to apply a quasi-experimental method (IV, difference in difference etc..). 
Finally, depending on how the sample has been collected and on possible variability within groups clusterd standard errors should be computed. I do not know the structure of your samle, but a possibility would be to cluster according to type of disability. To check the within variation you can compute the Inter correlation coefficient.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tested my SEM in a qq plot and it isn't a normal distribution. Is their a non parametric variant for the OLS?

Comment: Thanks again!  I used the two way repeated measure ANOVA :)